# What algorithms does zip use in order to compress an image?

Tags: zip

I have found this [link on Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-does-file-compression-work/answer/Michal-Fori%C5%A1ek?srid=uL3Ch) which lists some algorithms, but I was wondering whether the zip command (in OS X) used all of them and in which order. I'm carrying out an investigation on image compression and I'd appreciate it a lot if you could help me out. Thank you beforehand!

---

Edit: I found this [website](https://zlib.net/feldspar.html) which explains the deflate algorithm in depth. I hope it's useful. Thank you all for helping me!

Comment: `zip` specifically uses the Zip file format (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29) which can use a variety of compression methods, the most common being Deflate.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x I know, thanks, but what I want to find out is which ones are used and their order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`man zip` on macOS 10.12.6:

> zip has one compression method (deflation) and can also store files without compression.

It goes on to talk about optional `bzip2` compression, but `zip -Z bzip2` confirms that this is not enabled in the macOS build of zip.

As for which one is used when:

> zip automatically chooses the better of the two (deflation or store [..]) for each file to be compressed.

Comment: But actually store is not a compression algorithm right? So basically it chooses if the compression (deflation) would be effective?

Comment: Right. Store is more effective than deflate if the file has already been compressed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!! (I'd upvote you but still don't have 15 of reputation, sorry)

Comment: @DiegoBernal Use the check mark next to the answer to [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)